# GridView DataSource always returns null

Tags: c#, sorting, gridview, datatable

I am trying to do sorting in a grid view (ASP.Net 4.5)

Code is very simple. Grid view has **AllowSorting** and **AutoGenerateColumns** set to **true**

Grid view is populated on button click using simple query like **SELECT * FROM TABLE**

Sorting event has following code (code may have some syntax errors as I just wrote it rather than copying it from original source):

```
protected void GridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = grid1.DataSource as DataTable;

    if(dt != null)
    {
        //do some sorting
    }
}
```

Problem is **dt** is always null. I tried using following but same issue.

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)grid1.DataSource;
```

I tried saving datatable (on button click event when gridview is populated) in viewstate and then when I call it in sorting method above, now dt is not null but it remains empty and there are 0 rows in it.

Why dt is null and how to do sorting?

**EDIT**

Code on button click is given below

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
sqlCmd.Connection = con;
sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select * from titles";
SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
grid1.DataSource = dtRecord;
ViewState["grid1"] = dtRecord;
grid1.DataBind();
```

Comment: How and when do you set the datasource property of the grid?

Comment: Please update the OP with the code of you setting `grid1.DataSource` along with the SQL statement.

Comment: Could you please give the line where you set datasource?

Comment: the syntax for this is correct `DataTable dt = (DataTable)grid1.DataSource;` problem is you are not showing us where you are initially setting the datasource initially for the grid1 please show all relevant code that pertains to your current problem and or issue..

Comment: I have updated question with button click event code.

Comment: Have you debugged through to confirm what the result of the SQL statement is? Do you also have the table name in the correct case form?

Comment: SQL statement runs fine because I can see gridview being populated with records.

Comment: Try converting it to a Binding Source. `BindingSource bnd = (BindingSource)grid1.DataSource;` then do `DataTable dt = (DataTable)bnd.DataSource;`

Comment: BindingSource is only available in WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the DataSource back to a DataTable, try something like this. After setting the DataSource of grid1, add this:

```
ViewState["mydatasource"] = dtRecord;
```

Then, add this into the Sort event:

```
DataTable dt = ViewState["griddatasource"] as DataTable;
```

For the sorting, try something like:

```
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "col1 desc";

DataTable sortedDT = dv.ToTable();
```

Final code would be something like:

```
protected void GridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = ViewState["griddatasource"] as DataTable;

    if(dt != null)
    {
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.Sort = "col1 desc";
        DataTable sortedDT = dv.ToTable();
        grid1.DataSource = dortedDT;
    }
}
```

Comment: BindingSource is only available in WinForms.

Comment: I have done this already but no luck. I solved it by calling that SQL statement again in GridView_Sorting event.

Comment: That seems slightly inefficient to run a SQL statement twice or more. What if you saved the dt globally and then just used it? Not ideal but more efficient than running the SQL twice or more times.